# iOS app exits after Google signin

Tags: ios, google-oauth, testflight

My app worked fine in development straight from the computer to the device. When using Testflight/other deployment services, I was able to sign into my Google account (required for the app's functionality).
However, in the production environment, the app closed once it returned from Google. When reopening it, I was already signed in, but it still closed within a second or two. I was able to move a switch before then, which indicates that the app wasn't frozen. The device console says `App exited voluntarily.`

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? Assuming you're running the app in a debugger, you can add an exception breakpoint (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html). Or you can symbolicate a crash log from the device.

Comment: I don't have a stack trace- it runs fine in debug, but when I run it from the deployment service it crashes. So the device console is the only log I have.

Comment: You should also have a crash log on the device. That would be most helpful to debug this.

Comment: I did look on the device's crash logs but nothing was there. The console said that it exited voluntarily.